# How would I dynamically populate a remote html page based on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I have a list of options of which users may select what they like. At the end of their selection I would like to give them the option to print a page giving them a checklist of the options they selected. Would this be possible in solely javascript and html?

Comment: I have been researching jspdf, could I populate the pdf based on user input?

Comment: if you dont want to use php to do this, dont tag the question with php

Comment: @Dagon thanks for the common sense which I obviously lacked

Comment: Please define "remote html". Will a user have it in their browser?

Comment: @joepd, yes I just meant that they would click a print link which would take them to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the selections to a global variable(such as `selOpts`) in the main page.  After the end of the selection, you can open a new window and access these selections in the javascript for the new window using `window.opener.selOpts`.  That way you can display the selected options in the new page any way you wish.

Comment: So if I have <input type="checkbox" value="5">Buy a llama</input>, what would I assign to the variable so that Buy a llama appears on this new page

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be possible with Javascript and HTML

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id=checkbox1><label for=checkbox1>Buy a llama 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" id=checkbox2><label for=checkbox2>Buy a llama 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" id=checkbox3><label for=checkbox3>Buy a llama 3</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" id=checkbox4><label for=checkbox4>Buy a llama 4</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" id=checkbox5><label for=checkbox5>Buy a llama 5</label><br>
  <input type=button id=print_checklist value='Print Checklist'>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#print_checklist").on("click", function() {
    var mypopup = window.open("about:blank");
    var myChecklist = "<h2>Quick Checklist</h2><ul>";
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
      myChecklist += "<li>" + $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").text() + "</li>";
    });
    myChecklist += "</ul>";
    mypopup.document.write(myChecklist);
    mypopup.print();
  });
</script>

</html>
```

I was typing a generic answer when I saw you comment. 
The `<input type="checkbox" value="5">Buy a llama</input>` is not a valid form of HTML.

You should use:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="5" id=checkbox5><label for=checkbox5>Buy a llama</label>
```

Now assuming you use jQuery (can be done with pure javascript but jQuery it's a bit less code).

It is important that you open the popup immediately after the click event otherwise it will get blocked by the browser and it will be treated like a popup.

Fiddler example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ayhL8caq/)